# Increasing value in database after time interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am working on a codeigniter project in which i am making a counter of every movie that is being clicked. Now i want if the user clicks the movie link the user is directed to the movie page and after 30 seconds the counter will be increased to 1. Currently the counter is increased on every click. Any Help???

Comment: Use JavaScript setTimeout to wait 30 seconds then send a post request to the server using AJAX?  On the movie page of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countr will be increased even every refresh too in this scenario, whatever you are saying for 30 sec interval ( you can use ajax request with a 30 sec timeout) but this seems like a buggy code what if some one closes it before 30 sec (browser) and you don't get any increment....

if you want to setup unique (views) use browser/ip/time based (for generic setup you can make it advance) and every time you get the request of counter addition check your db if you have same ip/browser and less duration as you say(30 sec or 1 min) then don't add other wise add 1 to script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for this.

Example code (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.post( "ajax/count_movie.php?id=3", function( data ) {
          alert("I'm done!");
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```